# Nil pointer dereference even with initialization

Tags: arrays, pointers, go

My goal is to declare an empty 2D array that is then initialized and then filled with values every time do() runs. The issue is that I am getting a nil pointer dereference even though I am initializing the array.

This is a simple version of what I am trying to accomplish on a server simulator.

```
package main

import "fmt"


type Srv struct {
    A *[][]int
}

func (s Srv) init() {
    arr := make([][]int, 0)
    *s.A = arr
}

func main() {
    s := Srv{nil}
    s.init()
    printSlice(*s.A)
    do(s.A)
    do(s.A)


}

func printSlice(s [][]int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}

func do(s *[][]int) {
    *s = append(*s, make([]int, 0))
    printSlice(*s)

    (*s)[0] = append((*s)[0], 5)
    (*s)[0] = append((*s)[0], 6)

    *s = append(*s, make([]int, 0))
    printSlice(*s)
}
```

I expect an output like [ [5 6 5 6] [] [] [] ] but instead I get nil pointer dereference.

Comment: `s.A` is `nil`, you cannot dereference `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Where init does `*s.A =`, it's dereferencing a nil pointer. `s.A` is not yet initialized at that point (i.e., it's `nil`), and `*` is the dereference operator. But it's only a problem because it's unnecessarily complicated in the first place. It should just be:

```
func (s Srv) init() {
    s.A = make([][]int, 0)
}
```

Comment: Where would that go? I made A a pointer because do() would not change A permanently